# Laravel 8 Authentication doesn't work after upgrade form 7

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8, php-7.4

As the title says, it just stopped working out of sudden. I have a custom guard:
`config.auth.php`

```
 'guards' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
  .....
 'providers' => [    
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
```

The user (or shall I say admin?) gets authenticated through login controller:

```
if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, ])) {
            return redirect()->intended('/check');
```

but the route 'check' returns `null`

```
Route::get('/check', function () {
    $user = auth()->user();
    dd($user);
});
```

`.env` session part:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=1200
```

No any errors logged out, no any clue whats wrong. This app also has laravel Passport for API logins, which work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this, replace provider with this:

```
'providers' => [
'admins' => [ 'driver' => 'eloquent', 'model' => App\Models\Admin::class, ],
```

Comment: I've downgraded to larael 7 and issue was still there. changing `SESSION_DRIVER=` to `redis` helped

Comment: try this $user = auth()->guard('admin')->user();  not its work for laravel 8 to